# IOS Geofencing when app is active (foregroundd) and inactive(background) ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, geofencing

1) I am coding a app that uses geofencing to invoke reminders(didEnterRegion) . Currently, the app is able to invoke the geofencing reminder when the the app is inactive (background) only. Hope to receive guidance on how should I proceed. Thanks.

Side Question:
2) How do you ensure that  didEnterRegion (geofencing) across all controllers in the app? Do I have to add didEnterRegion method in all viewcontrollers?

Setup

I have a NSObject file (locationSingleton) which initialise CLLocation which can be across all my viewcontroller. Also, my didEnterRegion for geofencing is situated at appDelegate.m.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 2: 
post notification when didEnterRegion happen and add observers to all ViewControllers that need to receive this activity.

Comment: This answer is viable for Billy's problem.